# Custom Element extend from input type range

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out how to retrieve the current attr. value of the input type range element.
The attr. value seems not be the 'internal attr. value' which is changed during slides.

**Javascript**

```
'use-strict';
(function(){
var fooProt = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

Object.defineProperty(fooProt, "bar", {
    value: {test: 1},
    writable: false,
    enumerable: true
});

fooProt.getMin = function() {
    return this.bar.test;
};

fooProt.attachedCallback = function () {
    this.addEventListener('change', function(){
        //get current value, following does not appear to work
        //console.log(this.value);
    });
};

var foo = document.registerElement('ex-foo', {prototype : fooProt, extends : 'input'});
})();
```

**Html**

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" is="ex-foo" id="foo">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTMLElement` doesn't provide you with a `value` property, but `HTMLInputElement` does:

```
var fooProt = Object.create(HTMLInputElement.prototype);
```

Comment: @fubbe: Thanks. I didn't even know `document.registerElement` was a thing!